Time series cross validation for trend + tree model
I have a time series data set with ~3 years of data sampled daily from 2021 to 2024. The data set exhibits a trend, and clear cycles with periods of 1 year and 1 week.  My goal is to forecast ~3 months out of sample.
Overall, my rough approach is to: (1) Fit the overall trend with a straight line (2) Fit the residual with XGBRegressor.
My question is how this approach would work with time series validation. I can think of two paths to go down:
(1) Fit a line to the entire data set and compute the residual. Now, perform expanding window cross validation to tune the parameters of the decision trees
(2) Perform expanding window cross validation from the beginning. Specifically, for each training window fit a line, and then fit a decision tree on the residual. Then compute the cross validation error. Repeat this for each iteration of the expanding window.
My concern is that approach (1) might constitute data leakage. In some sense, the residual in e.g. 2021 "knows" about the data from "2024" because the later data was used to fit the trend line.  However, I'm not sure whether the residual in 2021 "knows" about the residual in 2024.  Can someone provide insight on which approach is right, and specifically whether there is anything wrong with approach (1)?


Fit a line to the entire data set

You have your data leakage right there.
I don't understand what you mean by your approach (2). Which "cross validation error" do you mean? "Real" cross validation, applied to a time series context, will mean that you pretend to learn from the future. If this is a faithful representation of your capabilities, I don't think you would be posting here.
The best way to test or validate any time series forecasting model is to use a true holdout set. Do all transformations (yes, even scaling) and model fitting on the first data points at time $1, \dots, T$. Forecast your model out to time periods $T+1, \dots, T+h$ and compare to the actuals. This is the only approach that correctly mimics the situation you will be facing when you actually forecast.
If you want to be fancy, you can do a rolling origin holdout test, where you roll the forecast origin forward in time, refitting each time. This gives you more data points, but of course means that each actual is used a different number of times in the evaluation. This is useful (and explains the term "time series cross validation", which I personally regard as unfortunate, because there is explicitly nothing "cross" about it, it's "rolling"!), as are actually all the resources listed at Resources/books for project on forecasting models.
